# Uninstall Phusion Passenger and repair package database

Tags: nginx, debian, apt

Some time ago I installed Phusion Passenger with these [instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu). I also have the debdeb.org repository in my sources.list.

I now want to remove Passenger and install a clean nginx package from dobdeb.org. Removing the `passenger` module wasn't an issue. But if I try to remove the `nginx-extras` or `nginx-common` package I get the following result

```
$ sudo apt-get remove nginx-common nginx-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  php5-apc
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nginx-common nginx-extras
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 2 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 1477 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2705 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

It seems my package database is broken in some way and I wonder why apache2 is going to be installed if I remove nginx-extras.

How can I remove nginx-extras and nginx-common without having to install apache2 and install a "clean" version afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume something you have installed has a dependency that is satisfied by nginx or apache2 being installed.

Try using `aptitude why apache2` and/or `aptitude why nginx-common` to see any potential relationships.

Comment: Good point. Owncloud has a dependency to `apache | httpd`. Maybe I try a force reinstall of nginx without the passenger repository in sources.list